# Adding a third Y-Axis to Excel Chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, yaxis, excel-charts

I'm generating multiple charts automatically using an Excel Macro. I already achieved adding two Y-Axis to the charts using  `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2` and editing the axis using
`ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)` . Is there any way to add a third Y-Axis to the chart using VBA?

Comment: Excel doesn't support a 3rd y-axis.

Comment: While Excel doesn't support this natively, you might be able to give the "appearance" of a 3rd y axis by automating the steps shown [here](https://engineerexcel.com/3-axis-graph-excel/)

Comment: Ok i will try automating that. Thanks